# Run a process and kill it if it doesn't end within one hour

Tags: python, process, kill

I need to do the following in Python. I want to spawn a process (subprocess module?), and:

- if the process ends normally, to continue exactly from the moment it terminates;
- if, otherwise, the process "gets stuck" and doesn't terminate within (say) one hour, to kill it and continue (possibly giving it another try, in a loop).

What is the most elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `subprocess` module will be your friend. Start the process to get a `Popen` object, then pass it to a function like this. Note that this only raises exception on timeout. If desired you can catch the exception and call the `kill()` method on the `Popen` process. (kill is new in Python 2.6, btw)

```
import time

def wait_timeout(proc, seconds):
    """Wait for a process to finish, or raise exception after timeout"""
    start = time.time()
    end = start + seconds
    interval = min(seconds / 1000.0, .25)

    while True:
        result = proc.poll()
        if result is not None:
            return result
        if time.time() >= end:
            raise RuntimeError("Process timed out")
        time.sleep(interval)
```

Comment: The downside of this approach though is that it is very expensive if there are lots of long-running processes, and very slow if process terminate quickly. An event-based solution would be much better, wouldn't it?

Comment: wait_timeout(proc, seconds) , what is a meaning of proc??

Comment: @jainamshah `proc` is short for "process"

Answer (score 11):

There are at least 2 ways to do this by using [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) as long as you know the process PID.
Assuming the process is created as such:

```
import subprocess
subp = subprocess.Popen(['progname'])
```

...you can get its creation time in a busy loop like this:

```
import psutil, time

TIMEOUT = 60 * 60  # 1 hour

p = psutil.Process(subp.pid)
while 1:
    if (time.time() - p.create_time()) > TIMEOUT:
        p.kill()
        raise RuntimeError('timeout')
    time.sleep(5)
```

...or simply, you can do this:

```
import psutil

p = psutil.Process(subp.pid)
try:
    p.wait(timeout=60*60)
except psutil.TimeoutExpired:
    p.kill()
    raise
```

Also, while you're at it, you might be interested in the following extra APIs:

```
>>> p.status()
'running'
>>> p.is_running()
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar question and found this answer. Just for completeness, I want to add one more way how to terminate a hanging process after a given amount of time: The python signal library 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

From the documentation:

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
    raise IOError("Couldn't open device!")

# Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)

# This open() may hang indefinitely
fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)

signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

Since you wanted to spawn a new process anyways, this might not be the best soloution for your problem, though.

Comment: This was by far the easiest of the answers on this page to implement.

Answer (score 1):

A nice, passive, way is also by using a threading.Timer and setting up callback function.

```
from threading import Timer

# execute the command
p = subprocess.Popen(command)

# save the proc object - either if you make this onto class (like the example), or 'p' can be global
self.p == p

# config and init timer
# kill_proc is a callback function which can also be added onto class or simply a global
t = Timer(seconds, self.kill_proc)

# start timer
t.start()

# wait for the test process to return
rcode = p.wait()

t.cancel()
```

If the process finishes in time, wait() ends and code continues here, cancel() stops the timer. If meanwhile the timer runs out and executes kill_proc in a separate thread, wait() will also continue here and cancel() will do nothing. By the value of rcode you will know if we've timeouted or not. Simplest kill_proc: (you can of course do anything extra there)

```
def kill_proc(self):
    os.kill(self.p, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Koodos to Peter Shinners for his nice suggestion about `subprocess` module. I was using `exec()` before and did not have any control on running time and especially terminating it. My simplest template for this kind of task is the following and I am just using the timeout parameter of `subprocess.run()` function to monitor the running time. Of course you can get standard out and error as well if needed:

```
from subprocess import run, TimeoutExpired, CalledProcessError

for file in fls:
    try:
        run(["python3.7", file], check=True, timeout=7200)  # 2 hours timeout
        print("scraped :)", file)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        message = "Timeout :( !!!"
        print(message, file)
        f.write("{message} {file}\n".format(file=file, message=message))
    except CalledProcessError:
        message = "SOMETHING HAPPENED :( !!!, CHECK"
        print(message, file)
        f.write("{message} {file}\n".format(file=file, message=message))
```